# Grey line above the window on Mojave

Tags: macos, ui, mojave

With the Mojave update a grey line appeared above every window, in either dark or light mode.

[image: Grey line above the window on Mojave]

Is it possible to remove that line? Any sort of hack of "hidden" setting? I've tried with:

`defaults write -app [AppName] NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool No`

But that needs to be set for every app, and just reduces it a little bit, it doesn't remove it.

Comment: it is a part of the design

Comment: More details at https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13164